# jQuery TypeError: data.incidentList[j] is undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays

I try to access a multidimensional array, this is structure

```
{  
   "incidentsNumber":176,
   "itemInterval":"3",
   "incidentList":[  
      {  
         "id":"849098658",
         "transactionId":"37035630",
         "timeStamp":"2015-05-17 09:14:27.440"
      },
      {  
         "id":"849098851",
         "transactionId":"37035638",
         "timeStamp":"2015-05-17 09:16:55.650"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
for(var j=0; j<=data.incidentList.length; j=(parseInt(j)+parseInt(itemInterval))) {
    var buttonid = '#btn'+ parseInt(j);
    $(buttonid).click(function (j) {
        console.log(data.incidentList[j]['transactionId']);
    });
}
```

But if I started with `j` from 1 I got the following error:

```
TypeError: data.incidentList[j] is undefined
```

if I started with `j` from 0 I don't get errors but buttons don't have actions on it. 
So my code doesn't work in any situations.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(buttonid).click(function (j) {
    console.log(data.incidentList[j]['transactionId']);
});
```

Why do you redefined `j` ? `j` will be the javascript `click` event. This is not what you want. If you write it like this, this new `j` will "shadows" the original `j`. Just remove this `j` argument and write this :

```
$(buttonid).click(function () {
    console.log(data.incidentList[j]['transactionId']);
});
```

You can also just rename this argument :

```
$(buttonid).click(function (event) {
    console.log(data.incidentList[j]['transactionId']);
});
```

Both codes will works.

Comment: Note though that as the op has it currently written, `j` will not be available outside the `for` loop...

Comment: I have tried with both solutions, now I don't have any error but also I don't have actions on buttons.